# Trigonometry unit circles

Tags: trigonometry

How is the $\cos A$ and $\sin A$ equal to coordinates on the unit circle? I have seen them becoming coordinates in first quadrant but I want to know how are they equal to coordinates in 2nd quadrant.

[image]

Comment: Step 1: Read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Step 2: Ask a good question.  That includes formatting of formulas using mathjax, and (important) include what you have done so far.

Comment: Was the explanation given clear to you. Please do not hesitate to ask for any other clarification about the topic. Bye!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that **by definition** $\cos A$ and $\sin A$ are precisely the coordinates of the point P(x,y) on the unitary circle such that ray OP forms an angle A with positive x axis (usually assuming as positive the counterclockwise direction).

[image]

Since the equation for the unit circle is

$$x^2+y^2=1 \iff \cos^2 A+\sin^2 A=1$$

which is the **foundamental trigonometric identity**, valid of course for every A and quadrant, from which all others trigonometric identities derive.

Comment: Gimusi.Formidable!!!!!

Comment: Gimusi.And loyal:)))