# inverse functions when solving trig equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

I am in Pre-calc this semester, and I have been given the problem:

$\cos(\theta) = -\frac12$

The answers I get are $30^o$ and $300^o$ but the answers I get from the homework key are $120^o $ and $240^o$. Why do the inverse equations give me answers that arent correct? Is there a better way to solve these problems? My work is as follows:

$\cos(\theta)=x$

$x= -\frac12$

$x^2+y^2=1$

$(-\frac12)^2+y^2=1$

$\frac14+y^2=1$

$y^2=\frac34$

$\sqrt y^2=\pm\sqrt\frac34$

$y=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

$\sin(\theta)=y$

$\sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

$\sin(\theta)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

$\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})=\theta$

$\sin^{-1}(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})=\theta$

$\theta=60^o,300^o$

Comment: Kudos to you for showing your work.  Put a backslash in front of a trig function to make it render correctly:  "\sin \theta" will show up as $\sin \theta$.  As for the answer to your question, there are two values between $0^{\circ}$ and $360^{\circ}$ that have the same $\sin$.  You used the wrong one for this particular value of $\cos \theta$.  Do you see why?

Comment: A better way would be to use $\cos^{-1}$ directly. Either way you should determine the possible quadrants of $\theta$ from the sign of $\cos\theta$.

Comment: $sin(\theta)=\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2}$ has 2 solutions; 60º and 120º. Similarly, $cos(\theta)=\frac{-\sqrt(3)}{2}$ has solutions 240º and 300º. So by using $sin(\theta)^2+cos(\theta)^2=1$, you introduced two extraneous solutions due to squaring

Answer (score 2):

Recall that, by definition, $\sin^{-1}$ has range in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ that is $[-90^o,90^o]$ therefore, since $\theta$ belongs to the third and fourth quadrant, we need to adjust the values as follows

- $\sin (60^o)=\sin (180^o-60^o)=\sin(120^o)$
- $\sin (300^o)=\sin (180^o-300^o)=\sin(-120^o)=\sin(240^o)$

which are the correct values.

In conclusion, your work is almost fine with this correction. In general, to solve this kind of equation I warmly suggest to refer to the [unit circle definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2661474/505767) for the trigonometric function, in this way the solution becomes trivial. Just draw a vertical line passing throught the point $(-1/2,0)$ and determine the intersection with the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin\theta=\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ implies that $\theta$ lies in the quadrant second or third, so $\theta$ is $\pi\mp\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{2\pi}{3}$  or $\frac{4\pi}{3}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How did you get the pi over 3 at the end?

Comment: Considering both $sin\theta$ and $cos\theta$ positive, the value of $\theta$ is $\pi/3$

Answer (score 1):

The formula for $cosine$ is given by :
$$cos\left(\theta \right)=\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$$
Since that :
$$cos\left(\theta \right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
So, it can be either :
$$-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}$$
or
$$-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{-2}$$
Since $hypotenuse$ cannot be **negative**, so it should be :
$$cos\left(\theta \right)=-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}$$
where :
$$adjacent=-1$$
$$hypotenuse=2$$
Since the value of adjacent is **negative**, so it should consist the angle in **second quadrant** and **third quadrant**. So, just use the formula :

Second quadrant :
$$cos\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=180^{\circ }-cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=180^{\circ \:}-60^{\circ }=120^{\circ }$$

Third quadrant :
$$cos\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=180^{\circ }+cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=180^{\circ \:}+60^{\circ }=240^{\circ }$$

So, the answer is :
$$cos\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=120^{\circ },\:240^{\circ }\:for\:0^{\circ }\le \theta \le 360^{\circ }$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been able to solve multiple similar problems with this method.

Comment: @TysonGrosz You are welcome. I do appreciate if you can accept my answer as the best answer. Thank you.