# Find the exact value of $\cos^{-1} (\sin \frac{4\pi}{3})$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the exact value of $\cos^{-1} (\sin \frac{4\pi}{3})$ without using calculator

The solution is $\cos^{-1} (\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}) = \cos^{-1} (\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \pi -\cos^{-1} (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) $

I completely do not understand how to solve these without the calculator.

First, how do we know that $\sin \frac{4\pi}{3} =\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ without the calculator, then why is $\cos^{-1} (\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \pi -\cos^{-1} (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) $ ? What identities are we looking at here?

I know that the range of inverse cosine function is $(0, \pi)$ and that means that the domain is restricted for $\cos A \in (0, \pi)$ for inverse of cosine to be defined.

Comment: $\cos (\pi -\theta)=-\cos \theta$

Comment: @geetha290km which part here represents $-\cos θ $

Comment: Take $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac {\sqrt 3} 2)$.

Comment: @user307640 For the first point, by symmetry, from the unit circle, we have that $\sin \theta = \cos (\pi/2-\theta)$ therefore $\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}= \cos (-5\pi/6)=-\cos (\pi/6)=-\sqrt 3/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\theta = \cos^{-1}x$ function, by definition, has domain $x\in [-1,1]$ and range in $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, such that

$$\theta =\cos^{-1}x \iff \cos \theta = x$$

we also have

$$\cos (\pi -\theta) = -x$$

and therefore

$$\cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\theta \iff \cos (\pi-\theta) = -x$$

that is

$$\cos^{-1}x + \cos^{-1}(-x)=\theta+\pi-\theta= \pi$$

which leads to $\forall x\in [-1,1]$

> $$\cos^{-1}x + \cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi$$

In this case we have $\sin \frac{4\pi}{3} = -\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ and $\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2\right)=\frac \pi 6$ then

$$\cos^{-1} \left(\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}\right)=\cos^{-1} \left(-\frac{\sqrt 3}2\right)= \pi-\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2\right)$$

---

For the first point, by symmetry, from the [unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2661484/505767), we have that

$$\sin \theta = \cos \left(\frac \pi 2-\theta\right)$$

therefore

$$\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}= \cos \left(-\frac {5\pi} 6\right)=-\cos \left(\frac {\pi} 6\right)=-\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$

or also

$$\sin \theta = \sin (\pi -\theta) \implies \sin \frac{4\pi}{3}= \sin \left(-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In which quadrant is the angle $\displaystyle \frac {4 \pi}{3}$, and what sign does $\cos \displaystyle \frac {4 \pi}{3}$ have?